# pandas accessing elements of the first row of a df

Tags: python, pandas

I am still learning pandas and am trying to access the first element of the first row of a named array like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
accel = [[-0.7437,0.1118,-0.6367],
         [-0.7471,0.1162,-0.6338],
         [-0.7437,0.1216,-0.6255]]
accel = np.array(accel,dtype=float)
angle =  [[169.4366,49.4714,56.9421],
         [169.3762,49.5374,56.8433],
         [169.2828,49.6582,56.7059]]
angle = np.array(angle,dtype=float)
avelo = [[-0.5493,-0.9766,1.4038],
          [0,-1.4038,0.7935],
          [0.061,-1.0986,0.2441]]
avelo - np.array(avelo,dtype=float)
dfs = {
    'accel': pd.DataFrame(accel, columns=list('xyz')),
    'angle': pd.DataFrame(angle, columns=list('xyz')),
    'avelo': pd.DataFrame(avelo, columns=list('xyz'))
}
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
param = df['accel']
val = param.head()
print(val['x'][0])
```

This (last three lines) does what I want, but it seems like a clunky way to do it. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)/[`IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) :

```
df.at[0, pd.IndexSlice["accel", "x"]]
#-0.7437
```

Or [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) :

```
df.xs(("accel", "x"), axis=1)[0]
#-0.7437
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iloc` to reference any specific row:

Code:

```
df.iloc[0]['accel']['x']
```

Output:

```
-0.7437
```

Comment: Looks like I can just also say df['accel]['x'][0] . But I also want to get the last value, and df['accel]['x'][-1] does not work like in a numpy list.  How do I get the last element?

Comment: `df.iloc[-1]['accel']['x']` will give you the last element, no changes to my suggestion required